# Generic Dictionary retrieve value

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have the following C# class:

```
class BatchData
{
    public string batchNumber { get; set; }
    public string processDate { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    public int SuccessCount { get; set; }
}
```

and a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, BatchData> BatchData = new Dictionary<int, BatchData>();
```

Now, I want to search the whole dictionary to see if the value

```
x
```

is held in:

```
BatchData.batchNumber
```

eg

for the whole dictionary, if

```
BatchData.batchNumber = x
```

I know Dictionary has a method

```
.contains
```

But I am not sure how I can apply this.

EDIT:

```
BatchData.batchNumber = x
```

Can occur multiple times within the dictionary

Comment: The point of a `Dictionary` is so that you can lookup things by key, not by something in the value.  It's not that you can't do what you are asking, but you won't be able to use the built-in `Dictionary` lookup methods to do it, and you certainly won't get the usual performance gains associated with a `Dictionary`.

Comment: If you are going to be doing a lot of lookups you should try to  make the key the value you are looking up (e.g. in this case make 'batchNumber' the key).

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `batchNumber` is unique for all batches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

`BatchData.Values.Any(x=>x.batchNumber == "x");`

For example:

```
Dictionary<int, BatchData> BatchData = new Dictionary<int, BatchData>();
BatchData.Add(1, new BatchData { batchNumber = "x"});
var hasX = BatchData.Values.Any(x=>x.batchNumber == "x"); //true;
```

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary is a collection of `KeyValuePair` objects, each of which has a `Key` property (an `int` in your case), and a `Value` property (a `BatchData` object).

There could be multiple entries with that batch number. If you just want to see if *any* key contains that number you can use

```
batchData.Any(kvp => kvp.Value.batchNumber == x);
```

If you want *all* key-value pairs with that batch number, change to `Where`:

```
batchData.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.batchNumber == x);
```

You can also use `First`, `Single`, etc. as appropriate.

Comment: This wouldn't work, you are assigning x when you should be testing equality

Comment: @Hammerstein Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1):

You should use `batchNumber` as the key to your dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, BatchData> BatchData = new Dictionary<string, BatchData>();
BatchValues.Add(batch1.batchNumber, batch1);
BatchValues.Add(batch2.batchNumber, batch2);
BatchValues.Add(batch3.batchNumber, batch3);
...
```

Then checking for existence is an O(1) operation ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx)):

```
BatchValues.ContainsKey(batchNumber);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work as he is expecting more than one value that would end up with the same key.

Comment: @RonBeyer - I have read the question a few times and that doesn't appear to be specified one way or the other.  Out of the fields that are specified, `batchNumber` is my best guess for a key field, but it is indeed an assumption.

Comment: Maybe I read it as getting a count or returning all of the items with that batch number, I guess its not clear if they just want to know if "any" contain that value, or to get all of them that do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another one solution by `Contains` method from `System.Linq`.

First, you need to implement `IEqualityComparer<>` interface

```
public class BatchDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<int, BatchData>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<int, BatchData> x, KeyValuePair<int, BatchData> y)
    {
        return (x.Value.batchNumber == y.Value.batchNumber);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<int, BatchData> obj)
    {
        //or something else what you need
        return obj.Value.batchNumber.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

After that, you can get value from Dictionary like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, BatchData> dic = new Dictionary<int, BatchData>();

    dic.Add(1, new BatchData() { batchNumber = "x" });
    dic.Add(2, new BatchData() { batchNumber = "y" });
    dic.Add(3, new BatchData() { batchNumber = "z" });

    bool contain = dic.Contains(new KeyValuePair<int, BatchData>(100, new BatchData()
    {
        batchNumber = "z"
    }), new BatchDataComparer());

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public class BatchData
{
    public string batchNumber { get; set; }
    public string processDate { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    public int SuccessCount { get; set; }
}
```